# Issue with active directory access from sql server agent job

Tags: sql-server

I have been stuck in this issue for such a long time. I can query active directory easily from ssms, but when i try same query from agent job, following error occurs:

```
> Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. The OLE DB provider
> "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI" reported an error. The
> provider did not give any information about the error. [SQLSTATE
> 42000] (Error 7399)  Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE
> DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI". [SQLSTATE 42000]
> (Error 7303).  The step failed.
```

Can anyone provide solution ? I selected NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE as my startup account in sql server agent

Comment: i think `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` has no permissions for AD access, select another login

Comment: I have already tried changing startup account of sql server agent still job runs under NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries, I checked 'Be made without using a security context ' and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Owner` property in job description and set logion with permissions:
[image]

Comment: when when i change owner of the job , it still gives same error as :

Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. The OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7399)  Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI". [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7303).  The step failed.

Answer (score 0):

If changing the Owner does not work (Login with having access to Linked Server), Try to create a Proxy Account in SQL Agent with that login and configure it in Job Step.

Comment: My query is of TSQL , how can i run it under proxy account?

Comment: Even with proxy account following error is seen: 

Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE.
 The OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7399)  Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI". 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 7303).  The step failed.

Comment: How you have configured the login setup of the Linked server?